# Installing MariaDB on Ubuntu: "Couldn't find package"

Tags: ubuntu, installation, apt-get, mariadb

I want to install MariaDB on my Ubuntu Server. The problem is that

```
apt-get install mariadb-server
```

returns :

> Couldn't find package mariadb-server.

I updated the packagelist with `apt-get update` but it still doesn't work.

What I've to do to install MariaDB?

Answer (score 4):

for anybody who has the same problem: look at this page:
https://downloads.mariadb.org/mariadb/repositories/

:)